# SAS, Make a macro variable contains YYYYMM

Tags: sas

I have a SAS statement. 
    %let data  = SampleData_200001_201603;

The data name is changing every time I run the code. For example:

run in 201604 then name= SampleData_200001_201603;

run in 201605 then name= SampleData_200001_201604;

run in 201606 then name= SampleData_200001_201605;

How can I write %let data =  ; to make it automatic? Thanks.

Comment: How do know to use `201603`?  Or for that matter `200001`?  Are you using the current date for the upper bound?

Comment: I run the code every month, so if the current month is 201603, then I will use 201602 for my data name.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the current date then you can use the `YYMMN6.` format to get the date in that format.

```
%let data = SampleData_200001_%sysfunc(date(),yymmn6);
```

If you need the previous month then use `INTNX()` function.

```
%let data = SampleData_200001_%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-1),yymmn6);
```

Comment: I run the code every month, so if the current month is 201603, then I will use 201602 for my data name. Thank you. At least I have an option!

Answer (score 0):

```
%let date = 201603;
%let data = SampleData_200001_&date.;
```

and loop through a list of dates

Comment: Superfluous, thank you. I am looking for an answer similar to Tom's. I do not want to manually type any date.

Answer (score 0):

I had enough of multiple %sysfunc's to get what I wanted. I wrote a macro routine that allows assignation of dates to macro variables using the format we want. No twists and turns with %sysfunc.

The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/dcomtois/3589a46c7328b9693ddfe2da0db22332). And it lets you do that: assign to a macro variable named "thisMonth" the value of `today()`, with format `YYMMn6.` :

```
%letdate(thisMonth, today(), fmt=YYMMn6.)

log says:
 *** Variable macro thisMonth = 201604 ***
```

And then

```
%let myFile = someName_&thisMonth;
%put &myFile;

log says:
someName_201604
```

The macro is documented in French but it should be self-explanatory for the most part.

**EDIT:**
Note that you can use any function normally reserved to data steps as the second parameter:

```
%letdate(firstDayLastMonth, intnx("MONTH", today(), -1, "BEGIN"), date9.)

log says:
 *** Variable macro firstDayLastMonth = 01MAR2016 ***
```